# pjsip receive sms

Tags: ios, sms, message, pjsip

Anyone know any good examples on how to setup a pjsip client to receive messages.
I can send messages from the client using:

```
pjsua_im_send(sip_acc_id, &to, NULL, &msgbody, NULL, NULL);
```

to any number.

But I have no idea what to do to receive messages into the already registered sip account.

Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I can only use pjsip and no other library.

**Edit:** Some new stuff I found:

http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/ticket/1070

http://www.pjsip.org/release/0.5.4/PJSIP-Dev-Guide.pdf (however all this document says about incoming msgs is this:

**16.1.2 Receiving MESSAGE**

Incoming MESSAGE requests outside any dialogs will be received by application
module.
Incoming MESSAGE requests inside a dialog will be notified to dialog usage via
**on_tsx_state()** callback of the dialog.

which still doesn't shine much light on how to handle incoming messages.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt

http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/SIP_Message_Buffer_Event

**Edit2:** I've been told that on_pager function needs to be used for this functionality. So I tried but still no success unfortunately.

Here is what I did:

```
/* Initialize application callbacks */
  app_config->cfg.cb.on_call_state = &on_call_state;
  app_config->cfg.cb.on_call_media_state = &on_call_media_state;
  app_config->cfg.cb.on_incoming_call = &on_incoming_call;
  app_config->cfg.cb.on_reg_state = &on_reg_state;
  app_config->cfg.cb.on_pager = &on_pager;
```

And the on_pager implementation:

```
static void on_pager(pjsua_call_id call_id, const pj_str_t *from, const pj_str_t *to, const pj_str_t *contact, const pj_str_t *mime_type, const pj_str_t *body) {

    NSLog(@"****************  on_pager called  **********************");
    AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[AppDelegate sharedApplication];

    pjsua_call_info ci;

    pjsua_call_get_info(call_id, &ci);

    PJ_UNUSED_ARG(call_id);
    PJ_UNUSED_ARG(to);
    PJ_UNUSED_ARG(contact);
    PJ_UNUSED_ARG(mime_type);

    [app ring];

    //PJ_LOG(3,(THIS_FILE, "MESSAGE from %.*s: %.*s (%.*s)", (int)from->slen, from->ptr, (int)text->slen, text->ptr, (int)mime_type->slen, mime_type->ptr));

    postMessageStateNotification(call_id, &ci);

}
```

I was expecting the application to call on_pager when a message is received but it didn't.
`on_incoming_call` however, does get called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out, what I did was correct, and it was just an issue with the server.
Receiving msgs is now working!

To sum it up, basically:

when registering for sip:

```
 app_config->cfg.cb.on_pager = &on_pager;
```

That will register for the on_pager() function to be called upon receiving an SMS.
The rest is up to you what to do on inside that function.

This is the function header:

```
static void on_pager(pjsua_call_id call_id, const pj_str_t *from, const pj_str_t *to, const pj_str_t *contact, const pj_str_t *mime_type, const pj_str_t *body)
```

I think everything is self explanatory for the function parameters, etc. Thanks everyone anyways for trying!

And app_config is passed inside the pjsua_init() function.

Also, in sipStartup() we register the NSNotification functions for iOS.

```
/***** SIP ********/
/* */
- (BOOL)sipStartup
{
    kSIPCallState         = @"CallState";
    kSIPRegState          = @"RegState";
    kSIPMwiInfo           = @"MWIInfo";

    if (_app_config.pool)
        return YES;

    self.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    if (sip_startup(&_app_config) != PJ_SUCCESS)
    {
        self.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        return NO;
    }
    self.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *phoneInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
    CTCarrier *phoneCarrier = [phoneInfo subscriberCellularProvider];
    NSLog(@"Carrier = %@", phoneCarrier);

    [self checkForConnection];

    NSTimer *timer;
    receiveCallTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
                       beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

                       }];

    //timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(checkForConnection) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


    /** Call management **/
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(processCallState:)
                                                 name: kSIPCallState object:nil];

    /** Registration management */
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(processRegState:)
                                                 name: kSIPRegState object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(processMessageState:)
                                                 name:kSIPMwiInfo object:nil];

    return YES;
}
```

and processMessageState: is below:

```
- (void)processMessageState:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"*****     processMessageState is called     *****");
    NSNumber *value = [[ notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"CallID"];
    pjsua_call_id callId = [value intValue];

    int state = [[[ notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"Event"] intValue];

    switch (state) {
        case PJSIP_EVENT_UNKNOWN:
            NSLog(@"unknown event");
            break;
        case PJSIP_EVENT_TIMER:
            NSLog(@"timer event");
            break;
        case PJSIP_EVENT_RX_MSG:
            NSLog(@"received --> rx_msg");
            break;
        case PJSIP_EVENT_TX_MSG:
            NSLog(@"tx_msg");
            break;
        case PJSIP_EVENT_TRANSPORT_ERROR:
            NSLog(@"msg transport error");
            break;
        case PJSIP_EVENT_TSX_STATE:
            NSLog(@"event tsx state");
            break;
        case PJSIP_EVENT_USER:
            NSLog(@"event user");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"processMessageState was called");
            break;
    }
}
```